# turn off an email account we can no longer access on the iPad

Tags: ipad, mail.app

After changing ISPs the former email account was removed, but our iPad still tries to log into it.

If we try to use the web interface it says the account is unknown. In the iPad Settings it says there's a problem logging in and asks to re-enter the password. In the meantime, all the controls for the account are greyed out until we successfully log in, which of course we can't.

I do not want to *remove* this account because it has years of archived emails. I simply want to turn it off. Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting your old email address off the ipad will not delete the account itself it merely removes the username / password from the iPad so it will not attempt to log in. But since you have changed ISPs anyway this is a moot point. Caution however make sure you have a backup of your archived mail in your possession on another PC or backup device before you do the following.

On your iPad go Settings>Accounts & Passwords

Select the mail account you want to remove

Scroll right down to where it says "Delete Account" in Red and click that - and again to confirm

you are done, your iPad will not try and access the account.

Comment: Will this method delete all the mail associated with this former account off of the iPad?

Comment: Yes it will, you need to backup what's on the ipad first then delete the account.